# Is it possible to declare and pass an array in one line in C++11?

Tags: c++11

I have a function with the signature `void add_world_triangle(float position[3]);`

Is it possible for me to call it with a line that looks something like: `render_state.add_world_triangle({-0.5, -0.5, -1});`?

Comment: `float position[3]` is adjusted to `float* position`

Comment: I suppose `add_world_triangle([](){static position[3] = {-0.5, -0.5, -1}; return position;});` doesn't count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void f(int const(&a)[3]);
void g(){ f({1,2,3}); }
```

If you don't ask for a reference, the array type decays to a pointer, which obviously cannot be built from `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: I would like to suggest the use of a typedef or using clausule for clarity: `using array3f = float[3]; void f(const array3f &a3f);` what do you think?

Comment: I agree that using a typedef is better, but in the answer I wanted to show how it can be written without a typedef, since the syntax is not completely obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <array>

void add_world_triangle(std::array<float, 3> position) {
}

int main() {
    add_world_triangle({-0.5, -0.5, -1});
}
```